# vb.net window.open

Tags: javascript, vb.net

```
    sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>")
    sb.Append("window.open('updateRT.aspx?batchno=" + batchno + "&prodcode=" + prodcode + "&maxrunningtime=" + temprunningtime + ",")
    sb.Append("top=0, left=0, width=500, height=500, menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,status=1,resizable=yes');")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "abc", sb.ToString())
```

hi everyone ...above is my vb.net code that i am trying to pass the value to other page and at the same time resize the window that will appear ...

i am not sure why and which error that i encounter and the size od windows still remain the same which is full screen rather than with width = 500 and height=500

can anyone help me out here?

thank you so much and have a nice day ...

:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, had misread your code.

You're supposed to pass in the window specification as the third parameter to `window.open` - check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp. Right now, you're passing everything in one parameter, since the comma which is intended to close the first parameter is actually part of a string. Try

```
sb.Append("window.open('updateRT.aspx?batchno=" + batchno + "&prodcode=" + prodcode + "&maxrunningtime=" + temprunningtime + "', '_blank',")
sb.Append("'top=0, left=0, width=500, height=500, menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,status=1,resizable=yes');")
```